# How to obtain Qt/PyQT widget style defaults, for instance table row height

Tags: python, qt, pyqt

I am using QListViews and QTableViews in my PyQt project and by default these both widgets use different size metrics for row heights. This lead me to try obtaining the default measures for certain QWidgets, but I haven't found a way to access those metrics without instancing a widget first (costful), only to then query its QSize.

Isn't there a better way, to query for such information? I was trying around with QStyle, but so far I haven't found a solution. Where does Qt define its style dependent size metrics for widgets and how to query those without instancing a widget?

Thank you for any hints into the right direction.

Comment: There are no such style dependent size metrics. Why don't you just set the row heights to the same value?

Comment: Because my intention is to go with some default size metrics. This leaves it to the OS style itself, instead of bothering with setting fixed sizes for all OSes. A pity that you cannot access those size metrics. From where does Qt gets the information when rendering widgets?

Comment: I don't understand. If you want to use the defaults, then just do nothing and let Qt handle it all for you. There is very rarely any need to use fixed sizes if you use layouts and size policies correctly.

Comment: An example for better understanding: Qt uses different default row heights when viewing models in a QTableView or QListView. I would like to set common row height for both widget types and instead of setting my own value I would like to use the default row height of QTableViews. I thought it might be unproblematic to query for the default style metrics. So far I ended up setting my own constant for row heights.